# Integromat date parser

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

How can I parse a **Text Field** with date information to a real date?

Here is an example string: `Thu, Jan 28, 10:00 AM CEST`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Integromat's Date & Time Functions](https://support.integromat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005771793-Date-Time-Functions): `parseDate` to achieve this. For your question using format `ddd, mmm dd, HH:MM tt zzz` should work.